# Navigation with Rails gem "acts-as-taggable-on"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to make an Navigation with specific Tags.
These Tags are for example: HTML, CSS and Javascript.
So when i click on one of them it will show all posts with these tag.
How can i achieve that?

My code for the Navigation right now looks like this (it's in the Application.html.erb)

```
<%= link_to "Computer", tag_list.Computer %>
```

I get this Error:

> undefined local variable or method `tag_list' for #<#:0x007feec764ff88>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tag_list` is a local variable or method, so unless you've created it in a helper that's your first issue. The second is that called `.Computer` on it doesn't work because tag_list is a method that created by the gem to list all an objects tags, and calling the `.` (also knowing as chaining) is attempting to call a method named Computer, which doesn't exist, that should just be a string and strings have to be quoted.

So, in your layout view, you can do

```
= link_to "Computer", tagged_posts_url(tag: "Computer")
```

Then in your `posts_controller.rb` add an action called `tagged`

```
def tagged
  if params[:tag].present? 
    @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else 
    @posts = Post.all
  end  
end
```

To maintain a DRY set of views, you can even tell it to render the index view since you most likely already have a list of posts, now it will look exactly the same but only contain posts with that tag. e.g.

```
def tagged
  if params[:tag].present? 
    @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else 
    @posts = Post.all
  end  
  render "index"
end
```

Then in your `config/routes.rb` add a route for your new controller action under your existing `post` route

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    get "/posts/tagged", as: :tagged
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already solved this myself but i will give your answer a try the next time :)
Still i will give you the right answer :))

Answer (score 0):

I got it myself.
Here is the Code:

```
<%= link_to 'Computer', { :controller => 'posts', :action => 'index', :tag => 'Computer'} %>
```

The controller looks like this:

```
def index
    if params[:tag]
    @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag]).order('created_at DESC')
else
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
end
end
```